# Quota limit for google API distance matrix & Excel VBA queries

Tags: excel, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

i'm using excel with VBA and the google API distance matrix to calculate distances between two locations each time for a long list of locations.
I use a google API with activated billing account associated to the API.
I use serviceweb in excel to retrieve the distance from google.
The formula in excel works fine but only for three queries, after I need to wait for a minute to resend three more.
In the quota page of google I see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m07Ca.png)
But it's not possible to extend the quota even though I have billing account associated.
is there something I'm doing wrong ? I would like to use the formula on several hundreds of lines containing the locations (each time to get distance between two different locations).

Thanks a lot for your help !!

I cannot change the quotas in google.
I looked at the quotas under the section "Premium plan Javascript API elements" and "Premium plan web service elements" and they would be perfect as the limit is super high but I can't get those to work..

Comment: For a related problem with quotas, I found the Google help personnel to be extremely helpful. I believe this was via chat.

Comment: You have to apply for quote increases

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As mentioned in the comments above, you need to file a support case for issues like this. Here's a link on how to: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support